# используя оператор расширения не проходит тест преобразовать к строке

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://js.cx/test/libs.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    "use strict";

    function makeBuffer() {
      let text = '';

      //используем деструктивные параметры
      return function(...piece) {
        if (piece.length == 0) { // вызов без аргументов
          return text;
        }
        text += piece;
      };
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Решение с тестами https://plnkr.co/edit/21ZpBDaIF3H2YPPDvbC3?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае `...` - это не оператор расширения, а синтаксис для определения [rest-параметров](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters).

Поэтому *piece* внутри функции является массивом, и при приведении *массива* к строке [действуют другие правила](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.join), а именно: если элемент *null* или *undefined*, то вместо него на выходе будет пустая строка.

Так как в тесте вызывается `buffer(null);`, внутри функции `piece=== [null]`

И при приведении к строке этого массива получается *пустая строка*.

Кроме того, если в функцию буфер передать несколько параметров, то на выходе они будут через запятую.

Если предполагается наличие только одного параметра, нет нужды использовать rest-параметры, достаточно явно описать один параметр.

Если предполагается возможность передавать несколько параметров, и поведение осталось прежним стоит изменить функцию `makeBuffer` работая внутри нее с *piece* как с массивом, например так:

```js
function makeBuffer() {
  let text = '';

  //используем деструктивные параметры
  return function(...piece) {
    if (piece.length == 0) { // вызов без аргументов
      return text;
    }
    text += piece.map(el=>el+'').join('');
  };
};

let buffer;
beforeEach(function() {
  buffer = makeBuffer();
});

it("возвращает пустую строку по умолчанию", function() {
  assert.strictEqual(buffer(), "");
});

it("добавляет аргументы в буффер", function() {
  buffer('Замыкания');
  buffer(' Использовать');
  buffer(' Нужно!');
  assert.equal(buffer(), 'Замыкания Использовать Нужно!');
});

it("приводит всё к строке", function() {
  buffer(null);
  buffer(false);
  assert.equal(buffer(), "nullfalse");
});

it("добавляет аргументы в буффер, несколько аргументов", function() {
  buffer('Замыкания',' ','Использовать');
  buffer(' ','Нужно!');
  assert.equal(buffer(), 'Замыкания Использовать Нужно!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://js.cx/test/libs.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно, поскольку форматом входящих данных является массивом. Когда Вы выполняете сложение массива со строкой, для массива выполняется операция `toString()`. Эта функция выполняет перечисление всех объектов и неизвестные объекты(`null`, `undefined`) в ней отображаются пустой строкой.

```
[null, false, undefined, 1].toString() // ",false,,1"
```

Кстати обратите внимание на запятую в качестве разделителя, это еще одна ошибка при формировании буфера.

Поэтому используйте явное сложение строки и параметров, а не строки и массива с параметрами.

```
<script>
     "use strict";

      function makeBuffer() {
          let text = '';

          //используем деструктивные параметры
          return function(...piece) {
              if (piece.length == 0) { // вызов без аргументов
                  return text;
              }
              piece.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
                  text += item;
              });
          };
     };   
</script>
```